# Insert Column with same value

Tags: sql

I am running a query on the table "performance" and I want to insert a column with the same value for all the rows without using alter, update etc.

I wrote a case statement and it works but is there a more refined way?

here is a short query:

```
SELECT id, name, class, 
       CASE 
          WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Actuals' 
          ELSE 'Forecast' 
       END AS type 
FROM performance
```

Basically I need all the values to be labeled "Actuals".

There are many other datasets for which I will use different labels and then append all of them

Just to be clear - don't need to update the table performance itself

Comment: Your question does not make sense without sample data and the query you are referring to.  A database tag would also help.

Comment: using UPDATE would be a more refined way but I am not sure why you dont want to use it.

Comment: what you have tried so far, which is a fix but you need more refined. Without knowing what you already tried it is difficult to ans.

Comment: You want to add a new column to the table? Or insert rows of data? Or update existing rows to change a column value for all rows? This is extremely unclear. Check out default constraints.

Comment: Just add a new column with same value

Comment: @userag123 . . . You should edit the question with additional details, not put them in a comment.  You will see a button to edit the question.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it). Do not put code into comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `common table expression` for your case. 
It will add new `column` in your existing data and you may use this for your further process.
For your point it is not adding nor inserting anything in your existing db structure.

```
  with CTE as (
  SELECT id, name, class, 
  CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Actuals' ELSE 'Forecast' END AS type
  FROM table_performance
  )
  select * from CTE   ----- It give you all the columns from [table] and add another column as you needed.
```

OR

You may create a `view` for same, if this condition is fixed.